# usememo and useeffect in customhooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've tried to use useMemo and useEffect in my custom hooks to prevent that from re-rendering ( doing cpu heavy job) which is parsing the JWT and returning the user permissions.
But it re-renders eveerytime that my menu items re-render and runs the usememo too.
Is there a way to avoid it from re-calculating ?

The code:

```
const usePermission = (controller?: string) => {
    const [permoactions, setPermoactions] = React.useState([]);

    const fetchPermoactions = () => {
        try {
            // parse jwt token and return permissions
        } catch (error: any) {
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }
    };

    useMemo(() => {
        fetchPermoactions();
        console.count("memo");
    }, [1]);

    const access = React.useMemo(() => {
        // make an permissions object tree
    }, [permoactions]);

    return controller ? access[controller] : access;
};
export default usePermission;
```

The usePermission hook is used in the pages where I need to validate for example if a user should see a button or have the ability to delete a line like this:

```
                    {permissions?.Create && (
                        <Grid item xs={2} sx={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
                            <Button
                                variant="contained"
                                onClick={handleAddClick}
                                endIcon={<AddIcon sx={{ marginRight: 2 }} />}
                            >
                                افزودن
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    )}
```

It's also used in the sidebar to not show the menus that the user doesn't have access to like:

```
    children = children.filter((child: any) => {
        let AccessList: string[] = child.name.split(",");
        let hasAccess = false;
        AccessList.forEach((Access) => {
            if (userAccess[Access]?.View) {
                hasAccess = true;
            } else {
                hasAccess = false;
                return;
            }

            return hasAccess && children;
        });

        return hasAccess ? child : null;
    });
```

Comment: The `useMemo` hook has a static dependency, so it should only run once, like if it had an empty dependency array. Where & how is this `usePermission` hook used? What are the "nav items"? Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese It's both used in nav items and in the pages I've added some examples to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to show where `usePermission` is used, where it's called, and that entire component to see what triggers it to rerender.